# RedirectToAction to an asynchronous method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have an `AccountController` and a `HomeController` with an `IndexAsync()` action

How do I properly redirect from the `AccountController`'s *AdminUserProfil* action to the *IndexAsync* action of the `HomeController`?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AdminUserProfil(AdminUserViewModel viewModel)
{
    // ...
    if (SomeCondition)
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction<HomeController>(h => h.IndexAsync());
    }
    // ...
}
```

If I use it as is I have a warning:

> **CS4014** Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current
>   method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the
>   'await' operator to the result of the call.

[image]

Comment: Are you 100% sure you need to make that action `async`? Is any other part of it `await`ing something inparticular?

Comment: @mariocatch updated the OP with an image of the (partially updated)code

Comment: Where does the `RedirectToAction<T>` method come from? Does it work if you just use what you had with `(h => h.IndexAsync)` (*without* the `()` that invokes it)?

Comment: @KirkLarkin the RedirectToAction is a Mvc Controller extension(MvcContrib.dll) it does not work without the `()`

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially executing the action in your example. You can use something like this to redirect to the action instead of executing it:

```cs
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Controller.ActionName),
                        nameof(Controller).Replace("Controller", ""));

// or hardcode controller name
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Controller.ActionName),
                        "Home");
```

If you need to return a task you can also

```cs
var result = RedirectToAction(..., ...);
return Task.FromResult(result);
```

Comment: That's up to you. You can either set a variable to what should be returned and then return it at the bottom, or you can return immediately once you know you're able to.

Comment: Note that `nameof(Controller)` would return "HomeController", but you want the string "Home" instead, to get this to work.

Comment: finally the `return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.IndexAsync), nameof(HomeController));` should do the work if I understood well

Comment: Yes, but as @JessedeWit pointed out, `nameof(Controller)` will also have the word `Controller` as part of the string. You can remove that or hardcode the controller string. I'll update answer.

Comment: so, there is not so much difference if the action is synchronous or not using that code

Comment: Correct, there is no awaiting involved when redirecting to an action.